# Can I restrict a template operator only for types that do not have that behaviour already specified?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Assume that I want to implement `operator<<` for all types. I would do:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, T&& t) {
    return out << "DEFAULT";
}
```

But this won't work because of ambiguity (in cases where the already specified `operator<<` is a free function). So I tried to restrict this with a `concept`:

```
template <typename T>
concept printable = requires(const T& t, std::ostream& out) {
    out << t;
};
```

This correctly reports that `int`s, `std::string`s and whatnot are printable, but `std::vector`s or `some_user_defined_struct`s (without overloaded `<<`) are not.

What I wanted was to use this `concept` with my (overly generic) `operator<<`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
concept printable = requires(const T& t, std::ostream& out) {
    out << t;
};

template <typename T>
requires (!printable<T>)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, T&& t) {
    return out << "DEFAULT";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::vector<int>();
}
```

But this lead to:

> ```
> In instantiation of 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T&&) [with T = const char (&)[8]]':
> recursively required from 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T&&) [with T = const char (&)[8]]'
> required from 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T&&) [with T = const char (&)[8]]'
> required from here
> fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use '-ftemplate-depth=' to increase the maximum)
>     6 |     out << t;
>       |     ~~~~^~~~
> compilation terminated.
> ```

It seems that there is an instantiation loop. In order to check whether we should use my `<<`, `printable` is being checked and by doing so, `<<` is attempted to be generated, which leads to a loop.

Is there any mechanism that would prevent such loop? Can we constrain types in such a way that the `template` will be generated only if it needs to? As for the use-cases, assume that, for some reason, I never want the compilation to fail when someone tries to `<<` something to `std::cout`.

Comment: Why not use `const T&` in your custom `operator<<`?  That way already existing `operator<<`'s will be selected in overload resolution assuming they also take a `const &`.

Comment: @IlCapitano because ultimately I would want this to work with `std::ranges` and applying `const` to them is a bad idea.

Comment: I think there's an answer for you at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534442/implementation-of-template-of-a-operator-c . The first answer limits the template to types which don't have `<<` defined already—the second answer limits types to iterable types which are not `std::string`.

Comment: @GILGAMESH "Note: The last example works in clang++ and MSVC but it fails to compile in g++ (recursion depth exceeded)." That's not really promising as I use GCC. And I wonder whether that enable_if boilerplate can be simplified by concepts. That's precisely why I tagged this C++20. Although the linked answers provide quite useful information. And for iterable types that are not std::string, I already can have requires on std::ranges::range and !same_as, so that's, imo, better than your approach.

Comment: @IlCapitano just checked, because it seemed weird to me - changing `T&&` (forwarding reference) to `const&` does nothing. It's still ambiguous for types such as `std::string`. Which, on the other hand, is weird, because I would believe that the standard overload is more specialised...

Comment: **Even if it was possible, I think it would be a bad idea.** That kind of things can easily make things break if someone else have the same idea elsewhere or if you don't always include the proper files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was messing around with this and was able to come up with something similar to what the question describes, the only difference being that you have to opt in to using it via a `using namespace` directive. ([godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Kx6P6))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
// T can be a reference type
concept printable = requires(std::ostream& out, T t) {
    out << std::forward<T>(t);
};

template <typename T>
requires (!printable<T>)
std::ostream& default_print(std::ostream& out, T&& t) {
    return out << "DEFAULT";
}

namespace default_ostream
{

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, T&& t)
requires requires { default_print(out, std::forward<T>(t)); }
{
    return default_print(out, std::forward<T>(t));
}

} // namespace default_ostream

int main()
{
    using namespace default_ostream;
    std::cout << std::vector{ 0, 1, 2 } << '\n';
    std::cout << "Hello!\n";
    std::cout << 2.234 << '\n';
}
```

This program will output the following with all of GCC, Clang and MSVC:

```
DEFAULT
Hello!
2.234
```

---

Putting the default `operator<<` in a seperate namespace and deferring the `!printable<T>` requirement to `print_generic` seems to work.  With this you will have to do `using namespace default_ostream;` if you want this behaviour, which cannot appear at global scope, but is fine at function (or some namespace) scope.

This works because `printable` doesn't see the generic `operator<<` when it's used as a requirement to `default_print`, that way it can't get selected for `out << std::forward<T>(t)` in the requirement and avoids recursive instantiation.
When you want to use the generic `operator<<`, you have to bring it into the local scope with `using namespace default_ostream;`, so it participates in overload resolution and because of its requirement it will only get selected if there's no other `operator<<` available.

Comment: This is absolutely great. Could you please explain why this works and what role does `using` directive play here? That would be a perfect answer!

Comment: @Fureeish Edited my answer and slightly changed the solution to use `requires` instead of SFINAE.

Answer (score 2):

You can't provide an operation if and only if the operation isn't provided. That's inherently self-recursive.

What you can do instead is add another layer of indirection. Like so:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void print(std::ostream& os, T&& t) {
    if constexpr (printable<T>) {
        os << t;
    } else {
        os << "DEFAULT";
    }
}
```

Comment: "*That's inherently self-recursive*" - well, true, but it's not like it's impossible. It depends on the point of view. One can claim the same for the specialized-case plus a fallback to a generic-case, but I can see where you are coming from. But you are probably right that it's impossible to achieve what I want. This indirection introduces inconsistencies in terms of the "original" `<<`ing, but that's a problem with streams themselves.

Comment: @Fureeish In cases like this, you can also just... provide a default. And then rely on customizations to be more specialized or constrained.

Comment: How would I "*provide a default*" so every user of my library can `<<` anything they desire and, in cases where there is no `<<` specifiec elsewhere, my version will be used?